# Can I change dataframe column label in a pipe using base R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do something like:

```
df %>%
  `attr<-`(.$column, "label", NULL)
```

To remove the label of a dataframe column, without having to load an external package just to perform this specific action (e.g. labelled, sjlabelled). Is it possible?

Comment: Hmmm....`%>%` is from an external package. But base R now supports its own pipe, `|>`.

Comment: `df |> transform(column = \`attr<-\`(column, "label", NULL))` would work.  Your attempt would work if you wrapped the `attr<-` call with braces - but this is a feature of `magrittr` not base R.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks, trasform() did the trick. The documentation warns that the function is really only intended for interactive use, but I think I'm fine. However, I'm curious about how to get the curly brackets to work. ```df %>% {`attr<-`(.$column, "label", NULL)}``` returns only the column, not a modified df.

Comment: To use braces to return the modified data frame you could do `df %>%  {attr(.$x, "label") <- NULL; .}`.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento. Do you want to make these comments into an answer so I can mark correct? Or else I can do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ritchie Sacramento for answers in the comments:

Option 1 (base R):

```
df |> transform(column = `attr<-`(column, "label", NULL))
```

Option 2 (requires magrittr):

```
df %>%  {attr(.$column, "label") <- NULL; .}
```